# How to use / convert / see .AFM / .INF / .MCY / .PFY / .SCR / .TTY font files?

Tags: fonts, file-format

I just purchased a very old font book with three CDs inside of it.
The names of the files are quite obscure to me (and I've been designing fonts since 2003), .AFM / .INF / .MCY / .PFY / .SCR / .TTY.
Usually all these formats in the same font folder, 6 files for 1 font.

I tried a lot of different applications to try and open them, but none of them could recognise them.

I even tried launching the installer for the application on an old Powerbook running classic (the application on the CD is for Mac OS 6.0), but Classic couldn't run it.

I also tried going to http://onlinefontconverter.com/ but it didn't work.

There has to be a way to do this... Obviously the software on the CD used to do it, maybe?

If someone knows how to open these font formats to use or preview them, I'd love to have a heads up :)

[image: font folder with old formats]

EDIT: I have successfully installed the conversion software from the CD onto a Basilisk-run version of Mac OS 7.5.3. I am now able to convert these strange files to .BMAP / FFIL font suitcases, but I still cannot create .PS / .AFM files for these fonts in order to convert them...

Comment: Maybe this answer is for you? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2564/what-can-i-do-with-afm-adobe-font-metrics-file

Comment: System 6 is to Classic what Classic is to OSX. Chances are you'll need a pre-1990 operating system (System 7.5 or earlier) to make use of the files. System 8 changed *a great deal* at the core of Mac operating. 25 year old software is 25 year old software. Without a 25 year old system to run it, it's pretty worthless and often can not be converted to anything useful today. I'm voting to close this question because it has little to nothing to do with graphic design and is better suited to SuperUser.com

Comment: KMSTR I read it and it isn't clear what files the OP has, as these files work together, I'm not just trying to convert .AFM files (which only contain kerning info), I have all the files that work w/ one font.

Scott Ok, close it if you will! Never understood the functioning of SE in this regard, so much subjectivity in bans / questions deleting. Fonts are crucial to graphic design, man... What if s/o finds looking 4 an answer to this question comes to this page, and it's closed & unsolved? Don't close the door on knowledge... We can all step away from out PCs if we want to stop learning.

Comment: Maybe you could try a font editor software , and then import your fonts in it... then export them again in a new format. For example, Fontographer http://old.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontographer/

Comment: Are you sure the main font isn't only the .afm? It should have a .pfm too that comes with it (maybe it's the .pfy? Never saw that before. ) That can be installed with Extensis (not sure of the new version though.) You can try opening the .inf in a text editor, maybe some clues there.

Comment: Can you please give us the complete names of the files and the names of there directorys? There must be a readme on the disc explaining which fonts are included (I mean the name of the fonts. For example the font "newfont" could use the file "01234___.afm" and more ...)

Comment: @go-me Fontographer cannot open any of the files in these folders - or maybe you meant an old version of Fontographer?
Some folders have PFM files in them, some don't. Which software by Extensis do you recommend?
Yes, the .INF files contain the names of the fonts for example: FontName (AgfaRotisSemisans)

Comment: Maybe try Suitcase Fusion, there's a free trial I think. I love it! http://www.extensis.com/font-management/suitcase-fusion/  I used Fontographer years ago, I don,t know how well it could work now!

Comment: @go-me Tried Suitcase Fusion, the app scanned the folder with the thousands of files and didn't find anything they could use. I am currently trying to launch the files from a host system that can read them.

Comment: Asking about *tools* which **may** used in the process of design, but not exclusively,  are no more about design than asking about an air compressor, which may be used in construction but not exclusively, is about carpentry.  Technical issues such as "why doesn't this software work" is practically *never* a design question.